# Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON' Possible Connection String Issue?

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, sql-server-2012, web-deployment

I'm attempting to deploy my first MVC application and I keep running into issues revolving around connecting to my sql server database. My current problem is that when I try to publish the site, I'm greeted with: SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. What I'm not sure of however, is if this is my main issue or just a symptom of a different problem all together. I think the issue has to do with my connection strings (although I certainly could be wrong about that), which I've tweaked about 20 different ways. My most recent attampt to get it to work looks like this:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" 
     connectionString="Data Source=*ip address*;AttachDbFilename=C:\*full path*\aspnet-SourceMvc-20130301025953.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-SourceMvc-20130301025953;Integrated Security=True"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

<add name="StqmContext"
     connectionString="Data Source=*ip address*;AttachDbFilename=C:\*full path*\Quotes.mdf;Initial Catalog=Quotes;Integrated Security=True"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I've spent all day researching the issue, which seems pretty common, but they all seem to offer different solutions...non of which have worked so far.

Some additional information about the application: It's an ASP.NET MVC 4 application. The database was constructed using the Entity Framework Code-First method and I'm running SQl Server 2012, Enterprise ed. on Windows Server 2008 R2. The application was originally developed on my Windows 8 machine using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate, and once I finished it, I moved it to my work machine with Windows Server 2008 R2 and am trying to publish it in Visual Studio Express 2012 Web Developer ed.

On a side note, how do you open a database that was created using code first in the sql server management studio?

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

```
Stack Trace: 

[SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +6676046
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +810
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +4403
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +84
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK) +55
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover) +368
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) +6704814
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +6705315
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions) +610
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +1049
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +74
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +6707883
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +78
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +2192
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +116
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1012
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +6712511
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +152
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +229
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(SqlConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +134
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(SqlConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +3805003
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +10955690
   System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +91

[ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.]
   System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +10955761
   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices providerServices, DbConnection connection) +48

[ProviderIncompatibleException: An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct.]
   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices providerServices, DbConnection connection) +242
   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection) +82
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext) +88
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input) +248
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() +524
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CreateObjectContextForDdlOps() +23
   System.Data.Entity.Database.Exists() +40
   SourceMvc.Filters.SimpleMembershipInitializer..ctor() +128

[InvalidOperationException: The ASP.NET Simple Membership database could not be initialized. For more information, please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=256588]
   SourceMvc.Filters.SimpleMembershipInitializer..ctor() +461

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +159
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +256
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +127
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +11
   System.Threading.LazyHelpers`1.ActivatorFactorySelector() +72
   System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore(T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory) +241
   System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock) +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 nextInChain) +145
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 nextInChain) +840201
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__31(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +266
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +146
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +202
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag) +112
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +839055
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +146
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +166
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__17(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +146
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +166
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +826145
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +146
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +166
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate endDelegate, Object tag) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +401
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__2(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +786250
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +146
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +166
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate endDelegate, Object tag) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +343
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +12550291
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you intend to use integrated security you need to turn [impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72wdk8cc%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) on:

```
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

Otherwise add username and password to the [connection string](http://connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012):

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User ID=xxx;Password=yyy;
```

Comment: For impersonation, he already has that turned on (in his connection string). Could be an issue with his IIS app pool user (needs changing to his windows user).

Comment: @mattytommo Connection string has impersonation but application does not. `<identity impoersonate="true" /> in web.config will direct asp.net to use the current Windows logged on user.

Comment: I added <identity impersonate="true" /> under <system.web> and I'm still getting the same error message

Comment: @wrigley06 Make sure you have impersonation enabled in IIS. [See here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730708(v=ws.10).aspx).

Comment: Hey flem, impersonation in IIS is enabled with the identity to impersonate set to Authenticated user.

Comment: Hey flem, your initial solution worked (setting identity impersonate to true) after I pointed IIS to a Sql Server File as opposed to Sql Server.

Comment: "after I pointed IIS to a Sql Server File as opposed to Sql Server" What does this mean?

Comment: I had an old app that I was converting to integrated security. Interestingly, deleting the `<identity impersonate="true"/>` is what made it work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Integration tests are passing but in debug mode your getting login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON', then I'd be adding [authenticate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-1.1/532aee0e(v=vs.71)) to the Web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows"></authentication>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error message when setting up a Scheduled Task, be sure to uncheck:  **Do not store password. The task will only have access to local computer resources.**

If you setup an account that requires a password, but you also have that box checked, it will *apparently* default back to the anonymous login.