# Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON' ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I am having a problem connecting to my Database (which is on a different location) via my MVC application.

To test the DB connection, I made a Windows Form Application and used it to connect to the database with the same connection string which I am using in my MVC app

```
Server=192.168.16.243; Database=Precision_DB;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

The Windows form application connects and retrieves data perfectly, but the MVC app is giving me the following error:

```
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.
[SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.]
```

I should mention that I am using NHibernate in my MVC app. Does that make a difference? how can I resolve this issue.

Please help

Comment: How can I check for impersonation?

Comment: It's somethign you do on purpose!

Comment: Currently I am using no impersonation in the Web App

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you intend to use integrated security you need to turn impersonation on:

```
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

Otherwise add username and password to the connection string:

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User ID=xxx;Password=yyy;
```

[reference :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557450/login-failed-for-user-nt-authority-anonymous-logon-possible-connection-string)

Critics of anonymous login claim that they can reduce overall Internet and network security because a secure authentication process is not part of the anonymous login process. In addition, user-specific pre-establishments are absent during anonymous logins, leaving critics warning that such logins might not be as anonymous as users would like because servers and IP addresses can be revealed.

Comment: I am using Trusted Security to connect to the database. Is it good practice to give Anonymous user access to the DB?